# Variable number of elements in 2d array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I want to initialize a 2d array which its elements number in each row is not constant.

Something like:
`int a[][] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5}};`

How do I achieve that?

Comment: In C, You can't!!!!!!!!

Comment: You just did. Those values can be changed, since you declared them as not `const`. If you want the number of elements to change, then you must use another data structure, such as `vector`.

Comment: try [std::vector of std::vector of nt](http://ideone.com/oMT48x)

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this using a raw 2d array. What you can do is use a vector that holds other vectors. For instance in your case you could do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5} };
```